# Dynamic height based on content above

Tags: html, css

I want to dynamically adjust the height of DIV container for fill the remaining space between the bottom of the page and the content above.

I've tried to use `height:100%` or `height:calc(100%- XX);` but the height of the segment above is not defined. How can I resize the container below?

So, in this pen, I want to remove the scrollbar and show the content in the entire page.

```
<h1>Ciao</h1>
<section class="container">
   <div>here
   </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyPqBv

Comment: The CodePen contents are not the same as in your question

Comment: @Raptor https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyPqBv

Answer (score 0):

To remove scroll and fill the page,

just add `postion: fixed;` in your css as required.

I made some minor changes in css to replicate what you needed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEgbdy

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
}
.bg{
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(100, 50%, 60%, 1);
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg">
 <h1 class="" style="background-color:white">Ciao</h1>
<section class="">
  <div>here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here here 
  </div>
</section></div>
```